# SMA 75 and 50 ohm difference

Tags: connector, impedance

I am looking at some SMA connectors. Now, I am using mostly 75 Ohm SMA connectors. Most of the connectors (cable mount) are 50Ohms. So, wat exactly is the difference between these 2 connectors. Apart from the impedance factor, how is the impedance controlled to make it 50 or 75 ohms ?
Is it some special coat or the compound used ? Can anyone explain it please ?

Comment: I can think of two ways. One: alter the composition or density of the dielectric material between the center conductor and the outer shield. Two: alter the geometry of the metal parts so the dielectric gap is thinner or thicker. They also may do both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 75 ohm version of a 50 ohm connector (at least for the SMA, N and BNC types that I've studied) raises the impedance in two ways, while keeping the mechanical interface identical.

a) Reduces the diameter of the pin through the connector, while keeping the diameter of the mating part. This increases the ratio outer/inner over most of the pin.

b) Reduces the length of the dielectric support in the connector.

Both of these methods increase the impedance of only part of the path through the connector. At low enough frequency, you could regard this as a simple averaging of impedance.

For high frequency work, you need to analyse the effect of sections of transmission line with different impedance. The high impedance line looks inductive, the low impedance line looks capacitive. The combination looks like a low pass LC filter. With the correct choice of lengths and impedances, the filter is matched. As the deviation from ideal impedance, and the length of the deviant section reduces, so the corner frequency of the filter increases.

It's the relatively large intentional impedance variations in a 75 ohm version of a 50 ohm connector that give them a smaller bandwidth than their native 50 ohm version. If you want high bandwidth 75 ohm connections, you need to use a connector that's been designed for that impedance from the ground up.

Answer (score 3):

The ratio of root (L/C) = Zo Is controlled by Precision geometry ratio of the signal diameter to the inner diameter of the outer conductor  for a given dielectric constant which is usually Teflon for PTFE